# Log4Net email appender is sending emails when the threshold has not been met

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration

I've got an appender that I thought should be configured to only send emails when logging at the ERROR level.

But I keep getting emails from the application which don't have any entries with the ERROR log level.

Is there something in this configuration that is "fooling" the appender into sending? Something to do with the lossy setting perhaps?

```
<appender name="SmtpErrorAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender">
    <to value="myemail@somewhere.com"/>
    <from value="someapp@config.com" />
    <subject value="Service Error" />
    <authentication value="None" />
    <smtpHost value="127.0.0.1" />
    <port value="25" />
    <lossy value="false" />
    <evaluator type="log4net.Core.LevelEvaluator">
        <threshold value="ERROR" />
    </evaluator>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%newline %-5level %date %message%newline%newline%newline" />
    </layout>
</appender>
<root>
    <level value="DEBUG"/>
    <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender"/>
    <appender-ref ref="SmtpErrorAppender"/>
</root>
```

Comment: Use a filter as below - the reason is this [(source)](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/logging-log4net-user/200509.mbox/%3CDDEB64C8619AC64DBC074208B046611C7694A9@kronos.neoworks.co.uk%3E) - "The Evaluator is implemented by the BufferingAppenderSkeleton and is therefore only supported
by appenders that extend this base class and provide support for buffering. The SmtpAppender
is one such appender. **The Evaluator is a pluggable object that is used by the BufferingAppenderSkeleton to determine
if a logging event should not be buffered, but instead written/sent immediately."**

Answer (score 1):

Set a log level filter within your appender.

```
<filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
  <levelMin value="ERROR" />
  <levelMax value="FATAL" />
</filter>
```

Comment: Will this mean that the lossy log will only contain ERROR and FATAL and none of the info messages leading up to the error?